# Creating a Trivia Quiz - I have a question about my for loop functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery

(I'm very new to coding, sorry). I'm creating a Trivia Quiz for my coding boot camp, using jQuery and Javascript. So far, I've gotten stuff to hide and display. Now the roadblock I'm facing is when I'm trying to start the Trivia Quiz.

(I will attach my HTML for reference as well).

I'm having issues with the following: 
1. getting my question to display properly (I find I'm only able to get it to display if I write $("#question").html(triviaArray[0].question);
2. getting answers I created in my triviaArray to display in individual buttons. 
3. I need to create a for loop, but I'm not too sure if I'm writing it correctly or not. I just need the for loop to loop through each of the questions I created (with their respective answers).

If I write $("#question").html(triviaArray.question); 
the question will not print onto the screen.

When I tried to do 
document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML += "" + triviaArray.answers + "";
it appears as undefined. I forgot what I had originally, but it listed as "object object"

Here's my current JS script:

```
// ================================= GLOBAL VARIABLES ==========================================

var triviaArray = [
    {
        question: "How many times is 'f*ck' used in Pulp Fiction?",
        answers: ["a. 252 times", "b. 265 times", "c. 287 times", "d. 301 times"],
        correctAnswer: "b"
    },
    {
        question: "How many days did Bruce Willis work on the film?",
        answers: ["a. 28 days", "b. 42 days", "c. 14 days", "d. 18 days"],
        correctAnswer: "d"
    },
    {
        question: "This movie cost $8 million to make. How much of that money went to pay the actors' salaries?",
        answers: ["a. $6 million", "b. $4 million", "c. $5 million", "d. $8 million"],
        correctAnswer: "c"
    },
    {
        question: "When John Travolta was reviving Uma Thurman's character, which two board games are seen in the background?",
        answers: ["a. Game of Life, Operation", "b. Monopoly, Game of Life", "c. Candyland, Operation", "d. Scrabble, Operation"],
        correctAnswer: "a"
    },
];

var count = 0;

// user's guess is either right or wrong
var rightGuesses = 0;
var wrongGuesses = 0;
var unanswered = 0;

// define variable for the timer
var timer = 0;

// timer functionality 
var intervalID;

// // INVESTIGATE: should I have an index of questions and answers? If so,
// var indexQandA = 0; 

// then the game should start w/ 0.
// var score = 0; 

// create a results page at the end instead ("<h3>this is how many you've guessed correctly " + correct + "! </h3>")
// jQuery manipulates HTML!

// ========================================= PROCESS ==========================================

// GOOD HOUSEKEEPING: Make sure that HTML div tags are created and represented.
// Try to figure out where I can console.log stuff.

$(document).ready(function () {

    // List out everything that needs to be hidden before starting the quiz.
    $("#question").hide();
    $(".choices").hide();
    $("#answer").hide();
    $("#timer").hide();

    //  When I click the button. it should start the trivia quiz.
    $("#btn4").on("click", startQuiz);

    // create a function startQuiz() to start the game. 
    function startQuiz() {

        // the following represents the Results page... meaning I have to create a results page. 
        $("#startQuiz").empty();
        $("#right").empty();
        $("#wrong").empty();
        $("unanswered").empty();

        rightGuesses = 0;
        wrongGuesses = 0;
        unanswered = 0;

        // whatever I hid, now I have to show it: 
        $("#question").show();
        $(".choices").show();
        $("#answer").show();
        $("#timer").show();

        // The timer should start running.
        // If the timer starts running, the button should disappear and the question should display.
        // timer();
    };

    // function timer() {
    //     timer = setInterval(countdown, 10000 * 3)
    // };

    // create a function nextQuestion() and have a for loop to generate the next question.
    function nextQuestion() {

        $("#question").html(triviaArray[0].question);
        for (var i = 0; i < triviaArray.length; i++) {
            document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML += "<button>" + triviaArray.answers + "</button>";
        };

    };

nextQuestion();
});
```

and here's my current HTML (for reference, in case my error is tied to naming conventions): (& don't worry, I have my proper links to CSS, jQuery, Javascript)

```
    <div class="container"> 
        <div id="quiz">
            <h1>Pulp Fiction Trivia Quiz</h1>
            <hr style="margin-top: 20px"> 

            <div id="startQuiz">
                <button id="btn4">START QUIZ</button>
            </div>

            <!-- Question / Answer section -->
            <div id="timer">
                <h3>Time Remaining:</h3>
            </div>
            <div id="question"></div>
            <div id="answer"></div>

            <!-- Display correct answer -->
            <div id="message"></div>
            <div id="correctedAnswer"></div>

            <!-- Track Stats -->
            <div id="right"></div>
            <div id="wrong"></div>
            <div id="unanswered"></div>

            <div class="choices">
                <!-- <button id="btn0"><span id="choice0"></span></button>
                <button id="btn1"><span id="choice1"></span></button>
                <button id="btn2"><span id="choice2"></span></button>
                <button id="btn3"><span id="choice3"></span></button> -->
            </div>

            <hr style="margin-top: 50px">
            <footer>
                <p id="progress">Question x of y.</p>
            </footer>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looping on the array that contains all your data, but you should be doing it on the array of the answers for a question. So your code should look like this for the first question

```
    function nextQuestion() {

        $("#question").html(triviaArray[0].question);
        for (var i = 0; i < triviaArray[0].answers.length; i++) {
            document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML += "<button>" + triviaArray[0].answers[i] + "</button>";
        };

    };
```

That will only work for the first question. Looking at your comments, you are on the right path. Maybe you should look a better way for looping, like forEach.